# Möbius tranformations such that $T(\Gamma)=\Gamma$

Tags: complex-analysis, mobius-transformation

If $T(z)=\dfrac{az+b}{cz+d}$, find necessary and sufficient conditions that $T(\Gamma)=\Gamma$ where $\Gamma=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|=1\}.$

**My solution:** Let $T$ be a Möbius map such that $T(\Gamma)=\Gamma$. Since $T:\mathbb{C}_{\infty}\to \mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ then $\exists a\in \mathbb{C}_{\infty}$ such that $T(a)=0$. Consider two cases: 1) $a\in \mathbb{C}$ and 2) $a=\infty$.

1) If $a\in \mathbb{C}$ such that $T(a)=0$. Then the point $a^{*}=\dfrac{1}{\overline{a}}$ is symmetric with $a$. Then $T(a^{*})=\infty$. Also it's obvious that exists $b\in \Gamma$ such that $T(b)=1$. Then $$T(z)=\left(z,b,a,\dfrac{1}{\overline{a}}\right)=\lambda \dfrac{z-a}{\overline{a}z-1}$$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. Since $|T(1)|=1$ then $|\lambda|=1$ and $\lambda=e^{i\theta}$ where $\theta \in[0,2\pi)$. Thus $$T(z)=e^{i\theta}\dfrac{z-a}{\overline{a}z-1}, \quad \theta\in[0,2\pi), \quad a\in \mathbb{C}. \qquad \qquad \qquad (*)$$

2) If $a=\infty$ such that $T(a)=T(\infty)=0$. Then since $0$ and $\infty$ are symmetric hence $T(0)=\infty$. Also $T(b)=1$ for $b\in \Gamma$. Then $T(z)=(z,b,\infty,0)=\dfrac{b}{z}$.

Thus, $$T(z)=\dfrac{e^{i\theta}}{z}, \quad \theta\in[0,2\pi). \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad  \qquad  (**)$$

Eventually, the set of Möbius maps such that $T(\Gamma)=\Gamma$ consists of $(*)$ and $(**)$.

Is my solution correct?
Would be very grateful if anyone can check my solution, please!

Comment: The Möbius transformations sending the unit circle to itself is a group, namely the one generated by those you mentioned ie. $z\mapsto 1/z, z\mapsto e^{i \theta }z, z \mapsto \frac{z-a}{\overline{a}z-1}$. Also after a Möbius transformation the unit circle becomes $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ and the group of Möbius transformations sending $\mathbb{R} \cup \{\infty\}$ to itself is $z \mapsto \frac{az+b}{cz+d}, a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{R}, ad-bc = \pm 1$ isomorphic to $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @reuns, I am not familiar with $PGL_2(\mathbb{R})$? Is the solution looks OK?

Comment: @reuns, But where is the mistake? Could you point out?

Comment: Let $f(z) = \dfrac{z-a}{\overline{a}z-1}$ and look at $z \mapsto f(1/z)$ does it match what you said in 2)

Comment: @reuns, I cannot understand your remark. Could you give more details? because it's quite difficult answer the question when the question is kind of weird.

Comment: I would recommend not using $a$ and $b$ the way you do, since you started out with $T=(\begin{smallmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{smallmatrix})$. That's overloading the letters. For (1) and (2), why would $T(a)=0$ imply $T(1/\bar{a})=0$? If by "symmetric" you mean "represent antipodal points on the Riemann sphere," then that would be $a$ and $\color{Red}{-}1/\bar{a}$. And what makes you think Mobius transformations preserve antipodality? They don't. The ones from $SU(2)$ do, but not other elements of $PSL_2\Bbb C$.

Comment: The Mobius transformations that preserve the unit disk form the group $SU(1,1)$. The transformation $-1/z$ swaps the interior and exterior of the unit circle $S^1$, so the transformations that preserve $S^1$ form the group $SU(1,1)\rtimes\Bbb Z_2$. The Cayley transform turns the unit disk into the upper-half plane, and conjugates $SU(1,1)$ to $SL_2\Bbb R$ (which preserves the upper-half plane) within $SL_2\Bbb C$.